# Setting up an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I am planning to use Eclipse for a small java project, which I will develop together with a couple of mathematicians - hence it is important to set everything for them in a way that they can easily open the project, run one of the configurations, have all the files included etc. How can I do it in Eclipse?

In IntelliJ (and VS for M$ languages, and any other IDE I can think of) you just create a project file and tell the other people to double click on it :) However, in Eclipse you start from selecting the directory for the workspace, and I am struggling to link it conceptually with a "project file".

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/documentation/

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

1. Define a Team Project Set, that can be used to import projects from VCS systems. To do this, share the projects to version control, and then export the projects using the Export/Team/Team Project Set wizard. That can be imported by the corresponding Team Project Set import wizard; then all files will be added.
2. You can define a Run configuration where you can make any important setting (e.g. memory limit size settings; default parameters, selecting project/executed file), and then share this configuration as a file. To do this, open the Common tab in the Launch configuration settings (Run/Run configurations...), and select Save as/Shared file. Then you can save this launch configuration to your project, and that can be used to execute the program (e.g. first time by right clicking it, and then it will be shown together with the run configurations. In every case, make sure that you set the path parameters in a workspace relative way - e.g. use ${workspace_loc}/../runtime-indigoviatra

This way you can define a lot of settings together.

Another way to handle this would be to provide a workspace prepopulated. For this to work you have to make sure that all your collegues use the same operating system (e.g. Linux) with the same set of plug-ins, otherwise there might be some problems.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. There are definitely differences in the platform (some people use Win, some people use Mac, and I use Linux), so I will try the first way. Seems like exactly what I need. Should I commit this team project set together with all the other files?

Comment: You have to make sure that the other team members might get the team project set file. If you use SVN, then you can give the SVN URL (using DAV) to them to download the file from there using a browser. If this is not possible, then you have to manually forward the file to them (however, it is still a good idea to version control these files).

Answer (score 0):

Select any workspace and just create a new Java project. If you want to send it to others; they have to import (as existing project into workspace) it. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you always want to select the workspace; choose it from
Preferences->Startup : Prompt for workspace